# Multiple models associated with devise user - fill in one model based on selection of role

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, devise, renderpartial

Im using devise for user registration with the fields: email, password, and role.

When the user selects a role from a select box (Student, Teacher, Admin), I want the app to render the nested fields for one of these roles. Each role stores different information and exists as a model in its own right.

I have a javascript which shows and hides the appropriate divs based upon the current selection.

The problem is, the form fails to submit unless I complete the fields for ALL models, rather than just the currently selected model. I realise this is because I am rendering all the partials and then simply hiding them with the javascript.

**Question:** How do I use the javascript to dynamically render ONLY the partial containing the model fields for the currently selected model?

New Registrations View

```
h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <h3>Login Details</h3>

  <br />
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    <div class = "col-md-6"><div class = "panel panel-midnight">
      <div class = "panel-heading"><h3 class = "panel-title">Create an account</h3></div>
      <div class = "panel-body">
      <div class="form-inputs">

        <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Enter email address" %>
        <br />
        <%= f.input :password, :required => true, :placeholder => "Password" %>
        <br />
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, :placeholder => "Confirm Password" %>
        <br />
        <%= f.input :role, :label => "I am a:", :collection => ["Student","Teacher","Admin"], :required => true %>
      </div>

      <h3>Profile</h3>


      <div id = "student_fields">
       <%= render partial: "student_fields", locals: {:f => f} %>
      </div>

      <div id = "teacher_fields">
        <%= render partial: "teacher_fields", locals: {:f => f} %>
      </div>

      <div id = "admin_fields">
        Admin
      </div>

      <br />

  <% end %>

  <br />

  </div>

  <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>


<! Javascript to show/hide specific fields for each role>


<script>


  $(document).ready(function(){
     if($('#user_role').val() != "Student"){
        $("#student_fields").css('display','none');
     }
     else{
        $("#student_fields").css('display','block');
     }

     $('#user_role').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "Student"){
          $("#student_fields").css('display','none');
        }
        else{
          $("#student_fields").css('display','block');
        }
     })
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
       if($('#user_role').val() != "Teacher"){
          $("#teacher_fields").css('display','none');
       }
       else{
          $("#teacher_fields").css('display','block');
       }

       $('#user_role').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() != "Teacher"){
            $("#teacher_fields").css('display','none');
          }
          else{
            $("#teacher_fields").css('display','block');
          }
       })
    });

  $(document).ready(function(){
     if($('#user_role').val() != "Admin"){
        $("#admin_fields").css('display','none');
     }
     else{
        $("#admin_fields").css('display','block');
     }

     $('#user_role').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "Admin"){
          $("#admin_fields").css('display','none');
        }
        else{
          $("#admin_fields").css('display','block');
        }
     })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot "render" only the fields that you want.  It can either show/hide (as you're attempting to do) or request a dynamic load of content (aka, AJAX).  If you'd like to go the latter route then consider changing your profile section to look like this:

```
<h3>Profile</h3>
<div id="profile"></div>
```

Then you'll need to set up the javascript to make a request to a unique url based on which role is selected and fill the #profile section with the results.  Here's a jquery-based idea...

```
$('#user_role').on('change', function(){
  switch( $('#user_role').val() ){
    case 'Teacher': targetUrl = '...'; break;
    case 'Admin': targetUrl = '...'; break;
    default:  targetUrl = '...'; break;
  }
  $('#profile').load( targetUrl );
});
```

A word of warning: it's often best to try to get things working *without* ajax and then add the ajax later, especially if you're just starting out.  You might want to consider a slightly modified registration that acts more like a wizard -- the user could first provide the user details (including role) and the response could be to ask the user to provide their role-specific details when the user is successfully created.